# How to change the default Open File... (folder) in Netbeans 8.2?

Tags: directory, default, netbeans-8

How can I change the default `Open File...` directory in Netbeans 8.2 for Java SE\ME\EE?

I've edited my `projectui.properties` file line `projectsFolder=DIRECTORY` but that only works for projects. I am trying to open individual files without opening the entire project.
File was found (Windows) under "C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike setting the default project directory in NetBeans, you can't modify the default **Open File...** directory because there is no such "default directory" to change.

NetBeans behavior when you select **Open File...** from the **File** menu (on Windows 10 at least) is as follows:

[1] On the first occasion within a NetBeans session the **Documents** icon will be pre-selected in the **Open** dialog window, and your **Documents** directory will be opened. That's just the way NetBeans works, and cannot be modified. Although you can change the **Documents** folder that will be opened, you probably shouldn't. See below for details**.

[2] Within the **Open** dialog you can obviously navigate to any alternative folder to open a file. Thereafter, within that NetBeans session only, that alternative folder will be opened by default on the subsequent **File -> Open File...** selections, until an alternative directory is selected.

~~~~~

** To change the **Documents** folder in Windows (which will also change the folder that NetBeans opens on the initial use of **File -> Open File..**):

- In Windows File Explorer select **Desktop -> This PC -> Documents** and right-click.
- Select **Properties** from the drop down menu, and then select the **Location** tab in the **Document Properties** window.
- Enter the name of the new folder to be used as the **Documents** folder and click **OK**.
- Restart NetBeans, select **File-> Open File...** and the folder NetBeans opens will now be the one you specified in the previous step.

That may appear to have the desired affect, but other Windows applications also use the **Documents** folder, and may depend on files in that folder, so it shouldn't really be changed without good reason. If you really need to open files in NetBeans that are not within any project the cleanest approach would be to place such files in the **Documents** folder if possible.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to move the NetBeansProjects in the Documents folder mentioned above to the desired place and to place a permanent symlink to the desired folder. Instructions for latter referenced here https://superuser.com/questions/1020821/how-to-create-a-symbolic-link-on-windows-10

Watch out if the secondary location could be temporary (like a network drive) that it's always in place before you launch Netbeans.